# Prove $B(x,\delta)$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove $B(x,\delta)$ is open.

What this question is asking me to prove...? I don't understand nor have a clue to approach the question...

Comment: Hint: what is the definition of an open set?

Comment: Remember that $B(x,\delta)$ is a set itself. You want to show that something is a subset of another set.

Comment: [Here you asked about the Hausdorff dimension.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416607/show-that-fc-has-hausdorff-dimension-at-most-zero). I am confused.

Comment: Don't let your math.SE account to your younger sister...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An open set $U$ is one such that for each point $p\in U$ there is a ball $B(p,\epsilon)\subset U$.

You're asked to prove that $B(x,\delta)$ is an open set using the definition above.

Answer (score 5):

To prove that $B(x,\delta)$ you should show that for every $y\in B(x,\delta)$ we find $r>0$ such that
$$B(y,r)\subset B(x,\delta)$$

**Hint** Draw a picture to see how to find $r$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $p\in B(x,\delta)$ so $d(p,x)<\delta$ in which $d$ stands for our meter. If we set $$\epsilon=\delta-d(x,p)$$ which is positive so you can easily show that the open ball, say $B'(p,\epsilon)$ is a subset of $B(x,\delta)$. This satisfies the definition of a open set.