# Can a set of critical values be dense?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth function. Sard's theorem says that the set of critical values of $f$, the image of critical points, has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This does not tell us that such set is discrete, as we see $\mathbb{Q}$ is not discrete in $\mathbb{R}$.

Can a set of critical values be non-discrete? Further, can it be dense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The set of critical values can certainly be dense. For example, let $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ be any bijection, and let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be any smooth function such that $f(x) = g(m)$ for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x \in (m - \frac{1}{4}, m + \frac{1}{4})$. (Such functions can be constructed using suitable smooth partitions of unity.) Of course, $\mathbb{Q}$ can be replaced with any countable subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Going further, can the set of critical values be uncountable? Can it have positive Hausdorff dimension (e.g., could it be the Cantor set)? [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/446049/41415) discusses the latter question, going into detail on what Sard actually proved — which, if I understand correctly (and I'm not certain I do), includes the statement that the set of critical values must have Hausdorff dimension zero for $C^\infty$ functions, but not for $C^k$ functions for $k < \infty$.

Answer (score 13):

The set of critical values can be dense. For a simple case, let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be any $C^\infty$ function with support in $[-1/2,1/2]$ satisfying $f(0)=1,f'(0)=0.$ Let $q_1.q_2, \dots $ be the rationals. Then the set of critical points of

$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb {N}} q_nf(x-n)$$

contains $\mathbb {N},$ and $f(\mathbb {N})=\mathbb Q.$

---

**Added two years later**: To give a simple answer to a question in Daniel Hast's post: Yes, the set of critical values can be uncountable: Let $K$ be the Cantor set. Then as is well known, there exists $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ such that $f=0$ on $K,$ $f>0$ elsewhere. Set

$$g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt.$$

Then $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R),$ $g$ is strictly increasing, and $g'(x)=0$ precisely when $x\in K.$ It follows that the set of critical values of $g$ is $g(K),$ which is uncountable.